# Cassandra - join two tables and save result to new table

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I am working on a self-bi application where users can upload their own datasets which are stored in Cassandra tables that are created dynamically. The data is extracted from files that the user can upload. So, each dataset is written into its own Cassandra table modeled based on column headers in the uploaded file while indexing the dimensions.

Once the data is uploaded, the users are allowed to build reports, analyze, etc., from within the application. I need a way to allow users to merge/join data from two or more datasets/tables based on matching keys and write the result into a new Cassandra table. Once a dataset/table is created, it will stay immutable and data is only read from it.

**user table 1**

1. username
2. email
3. employee id

**user table 2**

1. employee id
2. manager

I need to merge data in *user table 1* and *user table 2* on matching *employee id* and write to *new table* that is created dynamically.

**new table**

1. username
2. email
3. employee id
4. manager

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: So somebody clicks something and you need to create table and go through table 1 and table 2, fetch matching stuff and write that to new table? And this is one time action, after that that table is only read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option that you have is to do the join in your application code. There are just few details to suggest a proper solution.

Please add details about table keys, usage patterns... in general, in cassandra you model from usage point of view, i.e. starting with queries that you'll execute on data.

In order to merge 2 tables on this pattern, you have to do it into application, creating the third table (target table ) and fill it with data from both tables. You have to make sure that you read the data in pages to not OOM, it really depends on size of the data.

Another alternative is to build the joins into Spark, but maybe is too over-engineering in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try and do the merge with Spark as the datasets can sometimes be large.

Answer (score 1):

You can have merge table with `primary key` of user so that merged data goes in one row and that should be unique since it is one time action.

Than when user clicks you can go through one table in batches with `fetch size` (for java you can check [query options](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.html) but that is a way to have a fixed window which will be loaded and when reached move to next fetch size of elements). Lets say you have fetch size of 1000 items, iterate over them from one table and find matches in second table, and after 1000 is reached place batch of 1000 inserts to new table.

If that is time consuming you can as suggested use some other tool like Apache Spark or Spring Batch and do that in background informing user that it will take place.